# Stripe Webhook does not work when I changed it to my domain and https

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to configure Django App with Stripe.

Webhook works well When setting the Endpoint URL using "IP address" and "http".

Here is the Endpoint URL.

> http://3.129.xx.xxx/subscriptions/webhook/

But when I changed it to my domain and add "https", It does not work.

Here is the Endpoint URL with my domain.

> https://mysite12345.com/subscriptions/webhook/

1.HTTP statas code is "time out".

2.Event type is "checkout.session.completed"

3.The log is "200 OK" but "Webhook event" is failed, it retries again and again but still failed.

4.Of course, the domain is valid(I can access other pages)

5.SSL certificate is issued by AWS.

6.Testing endpoint just manually do a POST request, it says.

```
KeyError at /subscriptions/webhook/
'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mysite12345.com/subscriptions/webhook/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'
Exception Location: /home/app_admin/venv_ruling/ruling/subscriptions/views.py, line 103, in stripe_webhook
Python Executable:  /home/app_admin/venv_ruling/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.8
Python Path:    
['/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/ruling',
 '/usr/lib64/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/lib64/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

In "Request URL:" it says "http" not "https" I also wonder if it's OK.

7.Below is request for Endpoint

```
{
  "id": "evt_1JFX0XJvSJBZN02KlqeHjJWi",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2020-08-27",
  "created": 1626841569,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a1VJ8H3hotDNG0bw8q583Q4r86u5J7Q0ZC4lrmCjXwwdNYE866YJiOmcza",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 3900,
      "amount_total": 3900,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://mysite12345.com/subscriptions/cancel/",
      "client_reference_id": "1",
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": "cus_JtJdr9wDqNEdBf",
      "customer_details": {
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "subscription",
      "payment_intent": null,
      "payment_method_options": {
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": "sub_JtJdTWtjY315lM",
      "success_url": "https://mysite12345.com/subscriptions/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      },
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_NX2udo8Xr4P94W",
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

I wonder why IP address and "http" Endpoint URL works well but a domain name and "https" do not.

When I changed "http" to "https" do I need to adjust something or am I missing something?

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information.

Thank you

Comment: Does your site have a valid HTTPS certificate?

Comment: @Paul Asjes Yes I have a certificate from AWS. Therefore URL in the chrome browser has a "locked key icon".

Comment: Can you send a request to your hooks endpoint using other means like curl?

Comment: @Jech Chua I updated the question by adding a request to Endpoint. Thank you.

Comment: No, I mean when I'm testing my stripe hook endpoint I just manually do a POST request to `https://mysite12345.com/subscriptions/webhook/`. What does it say if you access it like that? It might give you more insight.

Comment: @Jech Chua  I updated the question at "6. Testing endpoint just manually do a POST request, it says..."

In "Request URL:" it says "http" not "https" I also wonder if it's OK.